# Creating TypeScript Data Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mixins

I am studying backend development using NodeJS and TypeScript. To start, I am checking this [sample inventory](https://github.com/martin-nderitu/inventory-manager-backend). While reading the models, I got confused because there is an interface that is both extended (but inside the Model wrapper) and implemented.

The interface:

```
interface SaleAttributes {
    id: string;
    quantity: number;

    // foreign key
    productId?: string;
}
```

Base Class:

```
export class Sale extends Model<SaleAttributes, SaleCreationAttributes>
    implements SaleAttributes {
.
.
.
}
```

This is the [complete code](https://github.com/martin-nderitu/inventory-manager-backend/blob/master/src/models/sale.ts).

Comment: The interface is not extended. `Model` is extended and that is a generic that uses the interface. The `Model` definition should show how the generic parameters are used

Comment: I see. How can I missed that! My mind was not working earlier lol. Is this some kind of common pattern in NodeJS?